# Как создать ключ SSH для пользователя Git?

Tags: linux, git, ssh

ОС- Ubuntu 16.04.

Имеем пользователя git, для него необходимо создать ключ SSH.

```
> su git
> whoami
git
> eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 1261
> ssh-add ~/gitadmin
Enter passphrase for /home/git/gitadmin: 
Identity added: /home/git/gitadmin (/home/git/gitadmin)
> git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

Всё хорошо. Нормально получили данные с репозитория.
Начав новый сеанс ключа как-будто и не было:

```
> exit
> su git
> git pull
Permission denied (publickey).
```

То есть ключ был принят только для текущего сеанса. Как его сделать постоянным ключом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ключ по умолчанию можно настроить в конфигурационном файле `~/.ssh/config`.
Добавьте туда такие строки:

```
Host: *
IdentityFile: ~/.ssh/gitadmin
```

Comment: Да, что-то я втупил.